# Unable to include custom font in android

Tags: android

I want to use "HelveticaNeue LT Std 45 Light" as font-family for textview in android.
Can you plz give me suggestions......

i tried with

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/signout"
    android:fontFamily="Helvetica Neue Std Lt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bookings"
    android:paddingRight="45dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

but Booking appears as bold instead of light.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add your custom font *.ttf file in the assets folder in your project directory. Now in your program you can add your custom font using the below code:

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "monocorsiva.ttf");
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.appName);
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Hope this might have helped you.

Comment: This is good, and remember to remove spaces from the file name

Comment: @user2677248: Same concept applies there also, its just that you need to have a custom listView, only then these custom fonts are possible.

Comment: I want to use the textview in listview. The textview is in another layout

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,R.layout.trips_for_today,new String[] { REZ_ID,VENDOR_ID }, new int[] {       R.id.rezidval,R.id.vendor_idval});

I wan to use the custom font for "R.id.rezidval,R.id.vendor_idval" textviews.

So here i cant use your code. Is it possible to use .ttf file in the layout.xml file itself?

Comment: Here my ContentView is different from the two textviews. So i can't get use the same concept as bcz i will get NullPointerException

Comment: Try: Just before, ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...), TextView tv=findViewById(R.id.URtextviewName) and apply font to tv. This should not throw any exception, as every widget once dragged and dropped, will be added to R.java file.